# problem passing variables into javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

For some reason when I hover over these objects, no matter what I get the FALSE alert.
why?

```
function hoverEffect(listType, button, animatedObject){

    var button = $(button), animatedObject = $(animatedObject), listType = $(listType);

  if($(listType) == true){

    $(button).hover(function(){
    alert("listType = true");
      $(this).stop(true, true);
      $(this).toggleClass("mouseIn", 1000, 'easeOutQuint');
    }, function(){
      $(this).stop(true, true);
      $(this).removeClass("mouseIn",  1000, 'easeOutQuint');
    });

  }else{

    $(button).hover(function(){  
    alert("listType = false");
      $(animatedObject).stop(true, true);
      $(animatedObject).toggleClass("mouseIn", 1000, 'easeOutQuint');
    }, function(){
      $(animatedObject).stop(true, true);
      $(animatedObject).removeClass("mouseIn",  1000, 'easeOutQuint');
    });

  }


}



hoverEffect(false, "#globalNavButton", "#globalNavButton");
hoverEffect(false, "#reelButton", "#reelButton");
hoverEffect(true, ".listHover");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

if($(listType) == true){

to

```
if($(listType).length > 0){
```

Comment: thanks that worked but ... wish I knew why. I see what you are doing but it should work to say if (listType == true) why doesnt that work?

Comment: $(null) evaluates a object and when you equate it to true the expression never evaluates to true.